# Netty Memory Leak about MpscAtomicArrayQueue

Tags: elasticsearch, out-of-memory, netty

image: [memory leak about MpscAtomicArrayQueue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HpfLy.jpg)

Env: ElasticSearch 5.5.1

I don't know why the object of MpscAtomicArrayQueue use so much memory and make OutOfMemory happened?

please help me

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me that the memory usage is caused by the per thread cache of the allocator. How you can configure the allocator in elastic search is behind my knowledge tho. That said usually netty also allows you to do it via System properties:

https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/4.1/buffer/src/main/java/io/netty/buffer/PooledByteBufAllocator.java#L102

Comment: Thanks, I thought you  are right , there are 13458  ElasticSearch client threads  here.

Comment: ouch... that's a lot :(

Comment: @NormanMaurer assuming 64 bytes per thread, 13458 threads eat up ~800 kB. is that a problem?